# Is there a way to map array items to function parameters in typescript directly?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs5, typescript2.0

I often end up with a situation where i got an array with arguments and have to manually break the array into parts. For example

```
Observable.combineLatest(obs1$, obs2$, obs3$).subscribe((data) => {
  let fancyArg = data[0];
  let epicArg = data[1];
  let wonderfulArg = data[2];
})
```

Is there a shortcut to do something like this

```
Observable.combineLatest(obs1$, obs2$, obs3$)
  .subscribe([fancyArg, epicArg, wonderfulArg] => { //something like this
    ...                                             //would be great
  })
```

I know that there is the option with the last argument as function

```
Observable.combineLatest(obs1$, obs2$, obs3$, 
  (arg1, arg2, arg3) => {
    return {
      fancyArg:arg1, 
      epicArg:arg2, 
      wonderfulArg:arg3
    }
  })
  .subscribe((args) => {
    ...
  })
```

but this is also very unhandy. I look for a more general approach (to use it by bindCallback and other functions as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript has [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) which you can use in your parameter list to unpack an array. Example:

```js
function takeAnArray([firstItem, secondItem, thirdItem]) {
  console.log(firstItem, secondItem, thirdItem);
}

takeAnArray([1, "a", false]);
```

So you were almost right in your second snippet. You just need to add a pair of parenthases around the argument list:

```
Observable.combineLatest(obs1$, obs2$, obs3$)
  .subscribe(([fancyArg, epicArg, wonderfulArg]) => {
    // Here, fancyArg is the first array element,
    // epicArg is the second
    // wonderfulArg is the third
  })
```

The [documentation for `combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) even shows this syntax in it's first example.

Comment: I tried so many variants. Thank you for the quick response ;-) Sometimes it's hard to find for me on search engines when I don't know the name

Comment: No worries. Happy to help. :)